# C#/XAML Using Saved String Data As Button/Label Content

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm fairly new to C#/XAML, however not necessarily new to coding in general (using Visual Studio).

I'm building a game launcher of some sort, and I'm trying to display a button content with saved string data, so that its displayed to the user each time the window is displayed.

I get my string data from my SQL database

```
            sql = "SELECT CNAME FROM TABLE WHERE MEMBERID = '" + user + "'";
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                Output = (string)dataReader.GetValue(0);
                if(char1 == "")
                {
                    char1 = Output;
                }
                else if (char2 == "")
                {
                    char2 = Output;
                }
                else if (char3 == "")
                {
                    char3 = Output;
                }
            }
```

And I want to use the data inside char1/char2/char3 as button content

However in doing this, I have failed multiple times

My code starting off, basically what I expected the end result to be:

```
namespace UGCAppp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for SelectChar.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SelectChar : Window
    {
        public SelectChar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UserIDLoggedIn.Content = "Logged in as: " + UGCLauncher.userId;
            this.DataContext = this;
            CharSlot1.Content = UGCLauncher.char1;
            CharSlot2.Content = UGCLauncher.char2;
            CharSlot3.Content = UGCLauncher.char3;
        }
    }

}
```

where UserIDLoggedIn = Label and CharSlot1,2,3 = Buttons, and UGCLauncher.userId, UGCLauncher.char1... = strings with stored values inside

I've tried multiple attempts at binding but none seem to generate the end result I need.

im stuck plz help ty

EDIT: Requested by Andrew, the issue I'm having is the buttons do show but the string data inside char variables are not showing up as button content on the buttons.

Here is the XAML code:

```
Window x:Class="UGCAppp.SelectChar"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UGCAppp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SelectChar" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/launcherbg.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="BACK" Content="BACK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" Height="35" Width="56" Click="BACK_Click">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/button7.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="MAIN" Content="MAIN" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" Height="35" Width="56" Click="MAIN_Click">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/button7.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="CharSlot1" Content="{Binding cha1, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,102,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="240" Click="Button_Click" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/button8.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="CharSlot2" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,217,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="240" Click="Button_Click" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/button9.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="CharSlot3" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,330,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="240" Click="Button_Click" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/button10.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Label x:Name="UserIDLoggedIn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="539,359,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Black" Height="48" Width="234"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

sorry for that ;;

Comment: Can you explain what is not working? Does your buttons show up but without the char contents? Also, it'd be easier to help with code around your buttons.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding sorry about that ;; i edited the post. Yes its the buttons showing up but without the char content as the button content

Answer (score 0):

This simple example shows you how to pass and show values in a `Window`.

- **Char1** is set directly to a `Button`.
- **Char2** is using binding to a `Button`.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Button
            Click="Button_Click"
            Content="Show SelectChar window" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectChar selectCharWindow = new(char1: "Char1 Button", char2: "Char2 Button");
        selectCharWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

**SelectChar.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.SelectChar"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Name="SelectCharWindow"
    Title="SelectChar"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="Char1Button" />
        <Button
            x:Name="Char2Button"
            Content="{Binding ElementName=SelectCharWindow, Path=Char2}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**SelectChar.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1;

public partial class SelectChar : Window
{
    public SelectChar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public SelectChar(string char1, string char2)
    {
        Char2 = char2;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Char1Button.Content = char1;
    }

    public string Char2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```